# How can I multiply an array length to manipulate another array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here are my arrays:

```
arr1=['a','b','c']
arr2=[[0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

What I want is getting this result:

```
arr1['a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c']
```

I mean یepending on the length of the second array, the elements of the first array must be repeated.
Both arr1 and arr2 are always equal in terms of elements.(3 here)

Comment: Would this be JavaScript or Python? It looks more like the latter...

Comment: What is this: _"arr1['a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c']"_? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
const arr3 = arr1
  .map((item, index) => Array(arr2[index].length).fill(item))
  .flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) here as:

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const arr2 = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
];

const result = arr1.flatMap((c, i) => Array(arr2[i].length).fill(c));

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) here as:

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const arr2 = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
];

const result = arr2.flatMap((na, i) => Array.from({ length: na.length }, () => arr1[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "flatMap" -- Please don't recommend things on SO with <99% browser support without pointing that out.  Flatmap is currently at 93%

Answer (score 0):

You can use two forEach loops like this :

```js
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr2 = [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

let result = [];

arr2.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.forEach(() => {
       result.push(arr1[index]);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
const arr2 = [[0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0]];

const res = arr2.map((v,i) => v.map(a => arr1[i])).flat();

console.log( res );
```